# Check if Google search has finished rendering the results on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to check if the user has run a search on Google search page using a Chrome Extension I am developing.

1. I am able to check if the user has click the search button on the Google search page.
2. But I am not able check if the actually has clicked one of the links from the suggested results. I mean nothing is printed when I do:

:

```
$('table.gssb_m table tbody td').click(function() {
   console.log('This is just awesome!');
});
```

So to debug this, I do the following to highlight the suggested results :

```
$('table.gssb_m table tbody td').css({'border': '1px red solid'});
```

The result is shown below:

[image]

Any idea why I am not able to output **This is just awesome!** when I click on one of the suggested result?

The whole idea is to check if the Google search has finished rendering the results. Thanks

Comment: Maybe because they are created on the fly. Try: `$(document).on('click', 'table.gssb_m table tbody td', function() {
   console.log('This is just awesome!');
});`